# How we can use intent for row items in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I start to learning jetpack compose in Android jetpack compose, I try to use intent for text menu items, I was saw many example for button on internet and in some books, but I want to use it for text row, I try to use below example, but app crashed, I do not know what I missed?

```
class MyActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyScreen()
        }
    }

}
@Composable
fun MyScreen(

) {

    val context = LocalContext.current


            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {

               MainRow(

                   name = "Menu1",
                
                   context.startActivity(Intent(context, Menu1Activity::class.java))

               )

                MainRow(
                    name = "Menu2",
            
                    context.startActivity(Intent(context, Menu2Activity::class.java))
                )
          }
        }
@Composable
fun MainRow(
    name: String,
  
    startActivity: Unit

) {

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {

           

            Text(
                text = name,
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    color = Color.Gray
                ),
            )

        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to open some Activivty after click on your row with text, first, you need add onClick modifier:

Comment: @bylazy, can you give a  short example , if possble

Comment: Add: If you want to open some Activity after click on your row with text, first, you need to add onClick modifier to your row, and second, pass a function: startActivity: () -> Unit instead of just Unit. (and then call it within onClick) Also, Compose designed to use only one activity for all your composables. Try to look at Compose Navigationv docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Composable
fun MainRow(
    name: String,  
    startActivity: **() -> Unit**
) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier**.clickable { startActivity() }**
                .padding(16.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text(
                text = name,
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    color = Color.Gray
                ),
            )
        }
    }
```

And call it like this:

```
MainRow(name = "Menu2", 
startActivity = **{**context.startActivity(Intent(context, Menu2Activity::class.java))**}**)
```

Comment: yeas it work tnx so much :)